# php, total count of a key with multi value inside a foreach (for) loop

Tags: php, api, for-loop, count

From an REST api, I convert the json data to array data by using

```
$return= json_decode($response, true);
```

There are 2 values for the same key inside each array, example:

```
['some1']=>array(
   [0]=> array(['data']=>0)
   [1]=> array(['data']=>1)
)
```

..
I did a for-loop to display the value of `['data']` in which the result are 0 or 1. Now I want to count the total 0 or 1 for `['data']` inside the whole array. How can I do that?
This is my for-loop looks like:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($return['some1']); $i++){
    echo  $return['some1'][$i]['data'] ."<br/>" ;}
```

echo shows:

```
0
1
```

Thanks,

Comment: Do you need the total of 0 + 1 + 1 etc... or do you need to know how many 1's there are?

Comment: Wouldn't that be the same number though, @VA79? the count of all `1`s is the same as the sum of all `1`s.

Comment: @Qirel you could also count all the 1s and then multiply by 1 to get the sum. :D

Comment: That would be true... :p gues i need some sleep! sorry :)

Comment: Haha, indeed @Don'tPanic :-) There's many ways to Rome!

Comment: I need to know how many 0 or 1 are there for ['data'], also it might be more ones or 0 inside that array for other keys but I do want total (how many) 0 or 1's for ['data']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply extract the `data` column and count the values.  The key will contain the value (0 or 1) and the value will contain the count:

```
$counts = array_count_values(array_column($return['some1'], 'data'));
echo $counts[0]; // return the count of 0s
echo $counts[1]; // return the count of 1s
```

If you had 2s in there then `$counts[2]` would contain a count of them etc...

Answer (score 1):

```
$count_0 = 0;
$count_1 = 0;
for ($i = 0; $i < count($return['some1']); $i++){
    if ($return['some1'][$i]['data'] == 0) {
        $count_0++;
    }
    if ($return['some1'][$i]['data'] == 1) {
        $count_1++;
    }
}
echo $count_0;
echo '<br/>';
echo $count_1;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know how many times each value of 'data' is repeated you can use something like below to keep track:

```
// Your input data
$data = array(
    'some1' => array(
        array('data' => 0),
        array('data' => 1),
        array('data' => 1),
        array('data' => 1),
        array('data' => 0)
    )
);

// Store the result
$result_array = array();

// Count each unique value for 'data'
foreach ($data['some1'] as $key => $value) {
    if ( ! isset($result_array[$value['data']])) {
        $result_array[$value['data']] = 0;
    }
    $result_array[$value['data']]++;
}

// Display unqiue results & their respective counts
print_r($result_array);
```

Example: https://eval.in/862097

Comment: I see, I admire you for using foreach-loop instead of for-loop but your solution print an array instead of a single number. However the solutions above yours return a number in which that was what I needed. Can you change your code to return the total as a number?